# Theorem 2.14 in Rudin's RCA: What is meant by "(a) forces (b)"?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, riesz-representation-theorem

Theorem 2.14 is the Riesz Representation Theorem(about functionals on $C_c(X)$):

> **Theorem 2.14**. Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and let $\Lambda$ be a linear functional on $C_c(X)$. Then there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak M$ in $X$ which contains all Borel sets in $X$, and there exists a unique positive mesaure $\mu$ on $\mathfrak M$ which represents $\Lambda$ in the sense that
> (a) $\Lambda f = \int_X fd\mu$ for every $f \in C_c(X)$,
> and which has the following additional properties:
> (b) $\mu(K)<\infty$ for every compact set $K\subset X$.
> (......the left omitted)

And a few lines later the author writes:

> $$ \mu_1(K) = \int_X\chi_K\,d\mu_1 \le \int_X f\,d\mu_1 = \Lambda f = \int_X f\,d\mu_2 \le \int_X \chi_V\,d\mu_2 = \mu_2(V) < \mu_2(K) + \epsilon. $$
> Incidentally, the above computation shows that **(a) forces (b)**.

"(a) forces (b)" is the problem. How this is possible? The author has just used (b) to show the above inequality, and says that (a) implies (b) by the above computation. I need explanation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know $\Lambda f = \int_X fd\mu$ for some $\mu$, then if $K$ is compact we can find some function $g$ that is $1$ on $K$ and compactly supported on $X$ and then this integral is at least $\mu(K)$ and must also be finite, as $\Lambda(f)$ is. So $\mu$ is then always be finite on compact sets. So for $(a)$ to hold at all, $(b)$ must be satisfied for the $\mu$ we want. I think that's all he's saying.

Comment: Why must the integral of g be finite?

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be compact there exists an open set $V\supset K$ and by Ursoyhn's lemma there exists an $f$ such that $K \prec f \prec V $ so that $0\leq f \leq 1$ and $f(X)\subset[0,1]\subset[0,\infty)$ which implies $\Lambda f\in [0,\infty)$ because $\Lambda$ is a positive linear functional so $\Lambda f$ is finite then since $\chi_K \leq f \leq \chi_V$ (by Ursoyhn's lemma) we have;

$$\begin{aligned} \mu(K)& =\int_X \chi_K d\mu \\& \leq \int_X f d\mu \\&= \Lambda f \\&< \infty \end{aligned}$$

so $\mu(K)$ is finite.